# Why does for ignore if statement?

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

I want to do 1D array with further conversion to 2D because I want to work with it via functions. There is an initialization function to create a system of coordinates, and then a function to draw it, but С ignores my `if` statement in creating the array function.

Code of initialization of array:

```
void inicialise(char* array, int width, int height, char ic)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        if (i == height / 2)
        {
            
            for (int b = 0; b < width; b++)
            {
                array[b] = 'x';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            
            for (int b = 0; b < width; b++)
            {
                if (b == width / 2) //x axis in middle
                {
                    
                    array[b] = 'y';
                }
                else
                {
                    array[b] = ic;
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Code of printing coordinates

```
void draw(char* array, int w, int h)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < w; b++)
        {
            printf("%c", array[b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
```

Real output:

```
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
00000000000y0000000000
```

Why X-axis isn't drawing?
Thanks a lot in advance for your answer!

Comment: I recommend you learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Then you should easily be able to see what happens, and when things go wrong.

Comment: Hint: look at where you use the height to address the row(s).

Comment: Where is the 2D part of the array? You seem to have only a single row. Regarding your question: The`if` is not ignored. You just fill the same memory again with `...000y000...` afterwards.

Comment: @Gerhardh yes, it is a single row, but function draw() draws it like [height][width] array

Comment: Look again, @BogdanReznikov: no, it doesn't.

Comment: You only modify `array[0]` to `array[21]` (assuming width and height of `22`). *And* that's the only thing you print as well. The rest of the array will remain uninitialized and unprinted. You need to involve *both* the line and row in the modifications and printing of `row`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Note that 11 + 11 + 1 is 23. (Oops - looks like it's *me* that can't count!)

Comment: No, it only draws it like a `[width]` array using same elements again and again for each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question, you are using a 1D array to represent what is actually a 2D structure (a matrix). This, in itself, is not a problem.

However, when doing so, you have to remember to add the 'row offset' to each and every index you use when accessing elements. This offset will be the row number multiplied by the width of the array.

In your code, each run through the outer (`i`-indexes) loops accesses the *same* row of the array (the first), because you use just the `b` index for every row – you are only ever writing (and re-writing) to the very first row of the matrix, so the output from the loop that writes the x-axis is replaced in the very next loop.

To fix this, you need to add a value of `i * width` to the array indexes you use. In your `inicialise` function, this will be like this:

```c
void inicialise(char* array, int width, int height, char ic)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        int row = i * width; // Offset for each row
        if (i == height / 2) {

            for (int b = 0; b < width; b++) {
                array[row+b] = 'x'; // Add row offset
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int b = 0; b < width; b++) {
                if (b == width / 2) {

                    array[row+b] = 'y'; // Add row offset
                }
                else {
                    array[row+b] = ic; // Add row offset
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, in your `draw` function:

```c
void draw(char* array, int w, int h)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        int row = i * w;
        for (int b = 0; b < w; b++) {
            printf("%c", array[b+row]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Taking the 22 x 22 matrix you have shown in your example output, a `main` function would look something like this:

```c
#define NROWS 22
#define NCOLS 22

int main(void)
{
    char test[NROWS * NCOLS];
    inicialise(test, NCOLS, NROWS, '0');
    draw(test, NCOLS, NROWS);
    return 0;
}
```

The output this generates is:

```
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
00000000000y00000000000
```

Answer (score 3):

When iterating over flattened 2D array you need to calculate index correctly:
I guess to fix your code you need to replace each:

```
array[b]
```

with

```
array[width * i + b]
```

The offset is `i` rows of `width` character each plus `b` characters.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way that the array is being indexed.  It should be indexed with something like `(i * width) + b`, where `i` is the row number and `b` is the column number.

The following should work as expected:

```
void inicialise(char* array, int width, int height, char ic)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < width; b++)
        {
            char val;
          
            if (i == height / 2)
            {
                val = 'x';
            }
            else if (b == width / 2)
            {
                val = 'y';
            }
            else
            {
                val = ic;
            }

            array[(i * width) + b] = val;
        }       
    }
}
```

and

```
void draw(char* array, int w, int h)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < w; b++)
        {
            printf("%c", array[(i*w) + b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Program output:
[image]